# Get bounding polygon coordinates from Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, geocoding

Does Google Maps(or any other provider[commercial/free]) provides API(s) that can return bounding polygon coordinates of place search? I'm not talking about sw-ne coords only, rather, actual boundary that perfectly defines the shape of a place. Place could be city, or more fine-grained identifiable place?

I don't know much about Google Maps API, but I did give it a fair share of searches and testing out sample codes(from examples provided by Google itself), as well as browsed through API reference, but couldn't find any.

Any help please...

Comment: Please explain why downvotes? Did I asked anything wrong?

Comment: No you didn't. I'm facing the same problem with you right now.

Comment: Stack Overflow is full of self-appreciated people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you mean is "is it possible to get boundaries of any place returned by Google Places API as we can see in Google Maps ?", the answer is no, you have to use KML files describing the polygon representing the boundaries of the place.

Depending of what you are searching for, it exists a lot of open-data KML files representing some state boundaries, for exemple [this file](http://data.vancouver.ca/download/kml/cov_localareas.kml) for example.
Please improve your question if you're searching something more specific, it is too broad right now. I didn't downvote, but I guess this why some other people dit it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.....I asked this because I can see Google does this when you search for any ae within a city, or even a mall or any public place. It draws a line boundary around it. I wanted that data.

Comment: I understand, but unfortunately, you'll need some KML file or get your own polygon representing the area you want to highlight